# django complex query filter

Tags: django, django-models

I need to make a complex filter that implies to apply a function over a model property.

The equivalent SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM myModel_table t WHERE abs(t.field1 - :binding_value) <= 50
```

where binding_value is a numeric received from the client.

Is there any way to define a field lookup using a funcion? Or do I have to directly use the raw sql?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the best way would be to use Django's queryset [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method:

```
MyModel.objects.extra(where=['abs(field1 - %s) <= 50'], params=[binding_value])
```

Answer (score 3):

If i'm not thinking the wrong way (please let me now if i am), you can "translate" you query a little to use simple django filtering.

First, it's True that:

```
abs(A - B) <= 50
```

is equal to:

```
-50 <= A - B <= 50
```

Then, this is equal to:

```
-50 + B <= A <= 50 + B
```

Then, your query could be like this:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(field1__range=(-50+binding_value,50+binding_value))
```

Comment: Yes, it would work with this filter, but i have to apply other functions in other parts of the application, and it would be more flexible to use the "extra" filter over the queryset. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

[Filter on an annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations):

```
from django.db.models import Func

class Abs(Func):
    function = "abs"

MyModel.objects.annotate(
    expr=Abs("field1") - binding_value
).filter(
    expr__lte=50
)
```

Edit: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35658634/10840