# How to filter using an expression in Django

Tags: python, django, django-commands

I'd like to filter that implements this "pseudocode":

```
   Post.objects.filter(Post.timestamp + Post.duration > datetime.datetime.now())
```

I also would like to wrap this in a Django management command.

Any help would be great!

Comment: You need to research how to write filter queries first; that's not valid Django at all.

Comment: I tried to solve this problem on my on. I found this documantation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/   I found a few errors I made but no solution to my problem.I would really appreciate help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Filter

Not sure how your fields look but here's a hint:

Let's compose an *F expression* like this `F('timestamp') - F('duration')`, and annotate our query with it:

```
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper, F

Post.objects.annotate(
        timestamp_minus_duration=ExpressionWrapper(
            F('timestamp') + F('duration'),
            output_field=DateTimeField()
        )
    )
```

Now you can filter with that annotated field

```
   Post.objects.annotate(
        timestamp_minus_duration=ExpressionWrapper(
            F('timestamp') + F('duration'),
            output_field=DateTimeField()
        )
    ).filter(
        timestamp_minus_duration__gt=datetime.datetime.now()
    )
```

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/#filtering-on-annotations

### Management Command

Just put the code in the `handle()` method of the command

```
# yourapp/management/commands/deletepost.py

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from yourapp.models import Post

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Describe your cmd here'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
           Post.objects.annotate(...).filter(...).delete()
```

More details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Can you give me a hint for the filter? The basic idea was, that timestamp is the creationdate and the user can pick how long the post should last. The timestamp comes from a DateTimeField and duration from a tupel of Durationfield.

Comment: I posted some hints, to annotate the value with an F expression and then filtering by it, that should do it. If you run into issues please post your model fields and I'll make actual code for it tomorrow!